# Is it possible to get folder names from a root URL using vb.net

Tags: vb.net

Say I have a root URL https://google.com/Files
I have 2 folders Temp1 and Temp2 under it (which can be accessed using https://google.com/Files/Temp1 and https://google.com/Files/Temp2. NOTE: I do not want to access them in this way)

How can I get the file path dynamically for these 2 folders using just the root URL? The folders might increase as and when required.

I had tried using GetDirectories method but realized it wont work on URLs.

Any leads will be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: what about something like `url.Substring(baseUrl)`? In this case `"https://google.com/Files/Temp1".Substring("https://google.com/Files/")` will result in `Temp1`

Comment: Are you asking how to send an HTTP request to a web server to list subdirectories? Most web sites would not be configured to allow that because it's not what most site admins want people doing.

Comment: @Marco I currently only have access to https://google.com/Files and do not want to use the hardcoded file path for the subfolders. I may have n number of folders under it. I want to retrieve the file paths of each subfolder dynamically. Hope you understood what I'm trying to say here

Comment: @John I thought of this case- but realized it wouldn't work for the exact same reason stated. Are there any other alternative functions used in vb.net that will allow me to access the folders? So far, it works for static files by using config keys